# R - ggplot: Get the id of a clicked graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Plotly has the function event_data which will respond to clicks on points of a plot. However, you have to specify a "source" for event_data which identifies the plot you want to watch.

Is this kind of feature available in ggplot too. If no, then how can we find the id of the clicked plot.

Note: I am refering wordcloud as graphs and these graphs are generated dynamically.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Look [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-selecting-points.html)

Comment: No, this is not what I want. Ex: Given there are 5 plots and if I click on any one from them, then I want the id of that clicked graph.

Comment: So you want to treat each plot like a big, fancy button?

Comment: Yes you can say that

Comment: The input `ID`s in the link I sent you can be named arbitrarily. Therefore it is possible to find out which plot was clicked like that..

Comment: I am not getting you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example that checks which Plot is clicked. The reactive value `selected_plot` will get updated whenever a click event happens.

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("text"),
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot1_click"),
  plotOutput("plot2", click = "plot2_click")
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  output$plot1 = renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(1000))
  })
  output$plot2 = renderPlot({
    plot(cumsum(rnorm(1000)))
  })

  selected_plot = reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {selected_plot(1)})
  observeEvent(input$plot2_click, {selected_plot(2)})

  output$text = renderPrint({
    cat("selected plot:", selected_plot())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that you can also specify the `click` option on the server side in using the `outputArgs` argument of `renderPlot`.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate your `ggplot` graph to a `plotly`-Graph calling `ggplotly(<yourplot>)` after you created it and use the `event_data()` function:

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]    
p <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + geom_point()
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I am having a wordcloud as the graph and don't want to convert it into plotly.

Answer (score 0):

it's difficult to explain without any example. However, when your work with `Shiny` thanks to the packages `ggiraph` you can change `geom_point` into `geom_point_interactive`, and later use something like this:

```
selected_dot <- reactive({
  input$plot_selected
})
```

Hope it helps a little